# How does Keras(Tensorflow) calc. shape of last layer Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm currently working on an image generating Conv NN and an audio generating Recurrent NN. I built for both the generators but for some reason the **build_audio_generator** model has in its last layer a Tensor (*Tensor("model_4/sequential_4/activation_4/Tanh:0"*) with shape **(?, 1)** instead of **(?, 28, 28, 1)** as needed. My question, how do I have to change the code of **build_audio_generator** so that it has the same shape(*?, 28, 28, 1*) as **build_generator**?

**Code:**

```
def build_generator(latent_dim, channels, num_classes):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation="relu", input_dim=latent_dim))
    model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    model.summary()

    noise = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    label = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')


    label_embedding = Flatten()(Embedding(num_classes, 100)(label))

    model_input = multiply([noise, label_embedding])

    img = model(model_input)

    return Model([noise, label], img)

def build_audio_generator(latent_dim, num_classes):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(512, input_dim=latent_dim, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(512))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))

    model.summary()

    noise = Input(shape=(None, latent_dim,))
    label = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    label_embedding = Flatten()(Embedding(num_classes, 100)(label))
    model_input = multiply([noise, label_embedding])

    sound = model(model_input)

    return Model([noise, label], sound)

# Build the generator
generator = build_generator(100, 3, 1)
audio_generator = build_audio_generator(100, 1)

# The generator takes noise and the target label as input
# and generates the corresponding digit of that label
noise = Input(shape=(None, 100,))
label = Input(shape=(1,))

img = generator([noise, label])

audio = audio_generator([noise, label])

print('Audio: '+ str(audio))
print('Audio shape: ' + str(audio.shape))

print('IMG: '+str(img))
print('IMG shape: ' + str(img.shape))
```

**Console output:**

```
Audio: Tensor("model_4/sequential_4/activation_4/Tanh:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Audio shape: (?, 1)
IMG: Tensor("model_3/sequential_3/activation_3/Tanh:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)
IMG shape: (?, 28, 28, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want 3D for audio instead, no?

Just keep `return_sequences=True` in all LSTMs.

Comment: Cool, that basically sovled my problem, but now I have a Tensor with shape **(?, ?, 1)**, how can I change the **?**, do I just have to reshape?

Comment: You don't need to care about that. The timesteps dimension will be considered variable internally, this won't change anything in results.

Comment: Also, `noise` input shape is (None, some_dim), so I assume you're intentionally working with variable lenghts, no?

Comment: So the extra two are fixed dimensions? But why is build_generator Tensor then not (?, ?, 1), but (?, 28, 28, 1). I'm sorry for my stupidity. (And yes I do work with variable lenghts)

Comment: One model is working with images, 2D convolutions, bringing 4D tensors. (They could also use variable sizes if you use `None` in the appropriate input shapes). The other model is working with recurrent layers, variable length, bringing 3D tensors. The middle dimension is the length (variable)

Comment: 28 comes from 7 upsampled two times.

Comment: Thank you very much, understand the obvious now :D